# How does CherryPy distinguish different http sessions?

Tags: python, cherrypy

In http://docs.cherrypy.org/en/latest/tutorials.html#id7 , there is tut05.py :

```
import random
import string

import cherrypy


class StringGenerator(object):
    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self):
        return """<html>
          <head></head>
          <body>
            <form method="get" action="generate">
              <input type="text" value="8" name="length" />
              <button type="submit">Give it now!</button>
            </form>
          </body>
        </html>"""

    @cherrypy.expose
    def generate(self, length=8):
        some_string = ''.join(random.sample(string.hexdigits, int(length)))
        cherrypy.session['mystring'] = some_string #(A)
        return some_string

    @cherrypy.expose
    def display(self):
        return cherrypy.session['mystring'] #(B) QUESTION HERE


if __name__ == '__main__':
    conf = {
        '/': {
            'tools.sessions.on': True
        }
    }
    cherrypy.quickstart(StringGenerator(), '/', conf)
```

I tried this program. When I use two browser sessions(imagine them as two clients from different computers) to visit the URL, the server can distinguish between the two clients. How is that achieved?

From the function body:

```
    @cherrypy.expose
    def display(self):
        return cherrypy.session['mystring'] #(B) QUESTION HERE
```

it looks that `self` is not reference, so I think `cherrypy.session` is the *same* object for two clients. Really same? Or where am I wrong.

Comment: It's set via [Thread-Local](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#thread-local-data) and such vars are different depending on thread. Note that each request is associated with exactly one thread.

Comment: Well, there's in-project implementation: https://github.com/cherrypy/cherrypy/blob/master/cherrypy/__init__.py#L223-L282